# Find all solutions for a complex logarithm

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

$\log z = 6i$

I am working on a problem very similar.

What I am seeing

$\log z = \ln|z| + i(\theta + 2\pi n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

What I am curious about, as if seen obvious to me that

$ \log z = 6i$

Can not exist as $6\geq\pi$

I have looked at polar coordinate such that 
$6i$ is equivalent to $e^{(6i)} =\cos(6)+ i\sin(6)$

Any thoughts on my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\log z = 6i$ where $\log$ is the principal branch of the logarithm, your remark is correct and no solution exists. If $\log$ can be any suitable branch however, then we can find $z$ simply by computing
$$z = \exp(6i) \approx  0.960170286650366 - 0.279415498198926i$$
There exist branches of the logarithm, such that $\log \exp 6i = 6i$. The principle branch will evaluate to $\log z = (6-2\pi)i$ nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to see if I can express this in terms of $x+iy$. Why would I use $6-2\pi$ to place the value in a computational sense? I do not need the principle, as I need all values of $i$ and the principle beach cut is a unique mapping.

Comment: @user141183 I don't understand your question. Do you want a closed form representation of $\cos(6)$ and $\sin(6)$?

Comment: Thanks, I firstly want to know why "The principle branch will evaluate to $\log z=(6-2\pi)i$.

Comment: @user141183 Because the principle branch choses the angle $\theta\in(-\pi, \pi)$. The angle equivalent to $6 \bmod 2\pi$ and in this interval is $6-2\pi$.

Comment: Ok, that was my intuition.